# Importing acoustic song (audio file) into Logic Pro X then adding drums and instruments

Tags: logic

I have an acoustic song I put out a few years ago.  I'd like to import it into Logic Pro X and then add some instruments, but I'm having trouble syncing the song tempo to the other instruments.  As a result, the drums, for example, are off with the tune.  I tried matching the project tempo to an audio region but that did not seem to be the right thing.

Is what I'm trying possible?  Anyone do this before?

Thanks.

Comment: Was the original acoustic song recorded to a click track?

Comment: As with all of these types of projects, you have to generate a tempo track manually that matches the actual beat, meter and tempo of the song. Unless the song was recorded to an accurate click you are likely to see significant variations in the tempo as the song progresses, however once you have done this part of the job, the tempo track will allow you to attach midi instruments to the project that are in-time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did not play with a click? That's the easiest way to get into that problem.

You need to set up automation for the tempo..
I hate doing it, which is why I recommend recording the guitar with the drums you've made (if possible)' which will really help to lock it in.

Otherwise, you need to go along, and on each beat, check if you are in synch. Start from the left and move slowly. If you are off, automate the tempo to speed up or slow down a little for THAT BEAT.

If the track is really off, you'll need to do a lot of this.

Answer (score 0):

I recently watched this video that demonstrates Logic's Flex & Follow feature for matching recorded audio to the grid. I haven't tried it yet, but looks as if it automatically stretches your audio to fit the grid, so your song fits the beat nicely.

The video shows someone recording very roughly to a click track, and layering multiple instruments, and them automatically being aligned to the grid. At the end he adds a Logic **drummer track** that seems to sync really nicely.

You can find the settings by clicking on the TEMPO box and then `Set Tempo Project Settings`, the `Flex & Follow` is shown there. Note that you need to `Keep Project Tempo` so you won't be fiddling about with small tempo adjustments.

[image: Logic Flex pr & Follow]

Answer (score -3):

Try using flex time. you'll have to think it through, but it should do the job!

Comment: Welcome to SD.SE! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Try not to just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.